# How Can I retrieve the value of BindingNavigator.PositionItem in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I retrieve value of BindingNavigator.PositionItem value into a variable?

for example

```
int rowindex = bindingNavigator.PositionItem.Text or value ?
```

[image]

I already know how to retrieve Datagridview index but I want to retrieve this value instead, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at the `BindingNavigator.PositionItem` property [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.positionitem(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The current position calculated by obtaining the **Position** property of the **BindingSource**, and adding 1 to transform the position into a 1-based count.

But I guess you just want to take the current row index, which can be obtained either directly from the `BindingSource` component or via `BindingNavigator.BindingSource` property like this

```
int rowindex = bindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using Position item from past one hour!